# Illegal characters in path in Html.RenderAction

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to call child action from view as below

```
@{
    Html.RenderAction("Render", "ProgressBar", new { total = 10, completed = 3 });
};
```

and my controller code is as below

```
public class ProgressBarController : Controller
{
    // GET: ProgressBar
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Render(int total, int completed)
    {
        ViewBag.Total = total;
        ViewBag.Completed = completed;
        ViewBag.Percent = ((completed * 100) / total).ToString("0.#####");
        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

and partial view for Render

```
<div class="section-progress-wrapper">
    <div class="section-progress-info clearfix">
        <div class="section-progress-label float-l">
            <span class="section-progress-output">@ViewBag.Completed</span>
            <span class="section-progress-desc">of</span>
            <span class="section-progress-total">@ViewBag.Total</span> modules completed
        </div>
        <div class="section-progress-icon float-r"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-progress-box">
        <div id="progressBar" class="section-progress-range" style="width:@string.Format("{0}%",ViewBag.Percent)"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but for some reason I am getting exception saying

> System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.

I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong. Can someone please help?

Comment: Could it be you are missing an open parenthesis on your style after the @ to enclose the whole statement?

Comment: no, because when I comment `Html.RenderAction` it works fine